# Angular form binding with async pipe to set the model

Tags: angular, angular-forms

If I have an observable I want to use as the default value for a form binding is there a way to have the async pipe set the model value of the binding?

```
<input type="text" name="value" [ngModel]="defaultValue$ | async"
  (ngModelChange)="model.value = $event">
```

This works fine but the value emitted by `defaultValue$` does not set `model.value`, it only populates the input.

Is there a way to use the async pipe to both write the value of ngModel and set model.value?

Comment: First thing I tried, `Cannot have a pipe in an action expression [defaultValue$ | async=$event]`

Answer (score 0):

I did this by creating a directive that watches the ngModel input and passes the value to ngModelChanges.

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[ngModelWatch]"
})
export class NgModelWatchDirective {
  @Input("ngModel")
  set update(value: any) {
    this.ngModel.update.emit(value);
  }

  constructor(private ngModel: NgModel) {}
}
```

and use it with

```
<input type="text" name="value" [ngModel]="defaultValue$ | async" ngModelWatch
  (ngModelChange)="model.value = $event">
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hvfyfz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html